# Error with Paperclip and RSpec 2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, paperclip

I'm trying to testing the paperclip methods in my model and I got the following problem:

```
1) InventoryImportRequest 
Failure/Error: it { should have_attached_file(:file) }
NoMethodError:
undefined method has_attached_file?' for #<InventoryImportRequest:0x000001064fc728>
# ./spec/models/inventory_import_request_spec.rb:7:inblock (2 levels) in '
```

My spec_helper.rb is configured as:

```
require 'spec/rails'
require 'paperclip/matchers'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/*/.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include Paperclip::Shoulda::Matchers
end
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2-p180, Rails 3.0.7, RSpec 2.6.0 and Paperclip 2.3.8

Comment: Can you post the relevant lines from your model spec?